# Python program to transfer contents from source file to destination file

Tags: python

I have to write a program that accepts two file names as input from the user: A source filename and a destination filename. Then, I have to write  a function that copies the contents of the source file into the destination file.

The program should work with any size and type of file (even binary formats like PDF/PNG etc).

Comment: Thank you for giving us your homework but SO is not the right place for it. Try it yourself and in the case of no success give us your code and we will try helping you.

Comment: got it! will keep it in mind henceforth :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you will have to consider that any type of file is "made" out of bytes. You will have to read the bytes from a file and then copy this bytes to another file.

You could take the CLI approach:

```
# program.py

import sys

# Take second and third elements from the arguments array (first one is 'program.py' itself)
sourceFileName = sys.argv[1]
destFileName = sys.argv[2]

# Open file 'sourceFileName' for reading as binary
sourceFile = open(sourceFileName, "rb") 
data = sourceFile.read()
sourceFile.close()

# Open (or create if does not exists) file 'destFileName' for writing as binary
destFile = open(destFileName, "wb") 
destFile.write(data)
destFile.close()
```

In this case you will pass the source and destination file names as the first and second arguments, respectively, in the command line, like so:

```
$ python test.py oneFile.txt anotherFile.txt
```

Note that `onFile.txt` should exist and `anotherFile.txt` may or may not exist (if not, it will be created)

You could also take the functional approach:

```
# program.py

def copyFile(sourceFileName, destFileName):
    # Open file 'sourceFileName' for reading as binary
    sourceFile = open(sourceFileName, "rb") 
    data = sourceFile.read()
    sourceFile.close()

    # Open (or create if does not exists) file 'destFileName' for writing as binary
    destFile = open(destFileName, "wb") 
    destFile.write(data)
    destFile.close()

    print("Done!")

# Ask for file names
src = raw_input("Type the source file name:\n")
dst = raw_input("Type the destination file name:\n")

# Call copyFile function
copyFile(src, dst)
```

You should consider adding a way of checking if the source file exists before opening. You could do this by using `os.path.isfile(fileName)` function.

Hope it helps!

Comment: this was really clear and helpful! thank you

Comment: @SamithKumar You are welcome! Please, if it helped you, pick my answer as the response to the question.

Comment: There are some disadvantages with the solution. If there is a large file, suppose 100gb, it would try to read the whole file at a time and load it to the primary memory.
Primary memory cannot handle this huge size of file at a time because they are usually in the order of 8gb to 16gb.

Can you suggest me a better answer where we can maybe find out the total size of the file and then copy chunks of it at a time?